# Can I make a peak voltage indicator with a small number of components?

Tags: voltage-measurement, hysteresis

I have a switchmode power supply that rectifies the main voltage with a full bridge rectifier and smoothes it with electrolytic capacitors. Assuming a 115 volt AC power supply, this gives a peak voltage of 162.64 volts DC on the electrolytic capacitors. We can call this +VDC

If the mains voltage drops under load, I would like to have a light that turns off on the display. This serves as a visual indicator that the mains supply has unacceptable voltage drop. This is common if you are in an older home or at the end of a long extension cord.

The first circuit I imagined is a 1N4007 connected to a tiny capacitor. This voltage source is connected to the base of a NPN transistor via a potentiometer and resistor. By adjusting the potentiometer, I can cause base-emitter current to rise as the +VDC crosses some voltage level. This would turn on the NPN transistor. The collector of the transistor would be connected to a LED and resistor fed from +5 VDC supply. The 5 volt supply would need to share a common ground with +VDC.

The above circuit would light once the base-emitter breaks down. The issue is the hysteresis on this would be enormous. Even if +VDC dropped significantly the NPN transistor would stay on enough to light the LED. I know I can use a resistor across the base-emitter to lower the hysteresis (and also gain). But I don't know if the solution would work well enough.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a reference such as a 12V zener diode and a comparator such as an LM393. It is dangerous working on circuits with relatively high voltage and especially those connected to the mains. It could be better for your health to use an unregulated AC adapter to provide isolation and connect your circuit to that. Or just buy an industrial voltage relay.

Answer (score 1):

A regular old d'Arsonval AC voltmeter IS a small number of components.
If it has to be a lamp, though, the low-parts-count winner is a
neon lamp driven from the AC with a voltage divider.   The threshold for a typical NE-1 lamp is 60V, but each lamp will have to be individually calibrated.

This kind of voltage tester used to be very common.

Answer (score 0):

ATX PSU with long gnd wires and dynamic loads can experience radiated and conducted  Noise immunity problems not necessarily due to line voltage dip.

Examine your noise immunity issues and DC fault thresholds in the ATX or MOBO or whatever to determine what your requirements are before you try to invent a mousetrap and end up chasing skinny rats instead.

DC ATX PSU's are "normally" designed to store enough energy to sustain a single cycle dropout and maintain regulation at full load, however internal line filters may not be adequate in rejecting transient line noise and end up coupling these transients into the output.  Linear transformers I have tested have a CMRR of about 60dB meaning a 1kV transient on the line side ends up in the isolated output of the DC regulated supply.  SMPS can be better or often much worse depending on the quality of the line filter.